# Flattening dataframe with separator to variable

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

How to assign this to a variable instead of printing it?

```
print(*df.values.flatten(), sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` will happily print string and non-string objects in a single statement. But when forming a string you have to perform the conversion explicitly. Here you can use `map` with `str.join`:

```
res = ','.join(map(str, df.values.flatten()))
```

Alternatively, you can convert your NumPy array to one containing strings:

```
res = ','.join(df.values.astype(str).flatten())
```

Answer (score 3):

I think to need convert values to strings if possible some not strings columns and then call `join`:

```
a = ','.join(df.astype(str).values.flatten())
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['b','b','c','d'],
    'B': list(range(4))
})
print (df)
   A  B
0  b  0
1  b  1
2  c  2
3  d  3

a = ','.join(df.astype(str).values.flatten())
print (a)
b,0,b,1,c,2,d,3

print(*df.values.flatten(), sep=',')
b,0,b,1,c,2,d,3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
','.join(df1.values.flatten())
```